# Creating a permanent roadblock

Tags: modal

I am currently in the process of trying to create a roadblock that will always run, with the exception of when we have a sponsored roadblock.

We have run into the issue of having a black square pop up when a sponsored roadblock stops serving, we are trying to prevent the black square from popping up when say for instance, someone forgets to delete the roadblock setting in expression engine. Is there a way to have a house roadblock constantly run, but stop running when we have a sponsored roadblock and then have the house roadblock start automatically running again, when the sponsorship roadblock ends?

Any insight is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you could set up a channel where you put the roadblocks into. also handy cause you can expire them automatically. then in your template do something like

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="roadblocks" dynamic="no" disable="categories|pagination|member_data|relationships"}
{if no_results}Do your default roadblock stuff{/if}
do the sponsored roadblock stuff
{/exp:channel:entries}
```